# about properties of homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

we know that the following shapes are homeomorphic

[image]

but in my book write :

Geometrically speaking, a homeomorphism is a bijection that can bend,
twist, stretch, and wrinkle the space M to make it coincide with N, but
it can not rip, puncture, shred, or pulverize M in the process.

now my question is :

we know that the above shapes are homeomorphic , but we $ \ can't $ bend,
twist, stretch, and wrinkle the space M to make it coincide with N. what is wrong ? what is relation between this question and homotopy and knot theory ?

Comment: The whole description that you quote of a homeomorphism is purely intuitive, and hence not its definition.

Comment: every loop is homeomorphic to a circle.
Continuous mappings are not always realizable as deformations.
Your intuition says that they are not isotopic.

Comment: What book are you referring to? Is it really a mathematics book?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net .Real  Mathetnatical   Analysis. by Charles Chapman Pugh .page 57.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples Is not that book good enough? I find OP's intuitive description ok.

Answer (score 1):

A better intuition for homeomorphic is that you are allowed to cut it apart, stretch it any any way, as long as you glue it back together with the same parts touching afterwards.

In the case of knots, they are all homeomorphic since you can always cut the string, unknot it, and then glue it back together to make a circle.

Knots are usually classified up to an "ambient isotopy", which means you are allowed to stretch the knot, but not cut it up at all, or let it pass through itself.

This is all pre-rigorous thinking though.  You really need to get practice carefully applying the definitions first.

Comment: So a Moebius Band cut , rotated by 180 deg and re-glued makes it homeomorphic to the Cylinder band?

Comment: @Narasimham No.  Even though the same edge is touching here, you have changed which points are close each other.  Some points which were originally quite close are now far away.  The cylinder and the Moebius band are not homeomorphic.  You can prove that they are not homeomorphic by noticing that orientability is preserved by homeomorphisms, but one of these spaces is orientable and the other is not.